# transform date into dummy variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, dummy-variable

I have this dataset

```
   df=structure(list(Data = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("01.01.2018", "02.01.2018", "03.01.2018", 
"25.12.2017", "26.12.2017", "27.12.2017", "28.12.2017", "29.12.2017", 
"30.12.2017", "31.12.2017"), class = "factor"), Y = 1:10), .Names = c("Data", 
"Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Date is date;
Y-is dependent variable

How can i transform days of date into dummy variable.
If the day refers to this date, then one, otherwise 0.

To be more clear, as output i expect

```
Data        Y   Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
25.12.2017  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
26.12.2017  2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
27.12.2017  3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
28.12.2017  4   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
29.12.2017  5   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
30.12.2017  6   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
31.12.2017  7   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
01.01.2018  8   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
02.01.2018  9   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
03.01.2018  10  0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

## Edit

here screen with days in excel with `WEEKDAY()` function
[image]

## Edit2

it is not dublicate, cause i need namely dataframe structure with 0 and 1 as desired output.
"dublicated " posts doesn't help me :(

```
library(dummies)

df1 <- cbind(df, dummy(df$Data, sep = "_"))
```

output

```
         Data  Y df_01.01.2018 df_02.01.2018 df_03.01.2018 df_25.12.2017 df_26.12.2017 df_27.12.2017 df_28.12.2017
1  25.12.2017  1             0             0             0             1             0             0             0
2  26.12.2017  2             0             0             0             0             1             0             0
3  27.12.2017  3             0             0             0             0             0             1             0
4  28.12.2017  4             0             0             0             0             0             0             1
5  29.12.2017  5             0             0             0             0             0             0             0
6  30.12.2017  6             0             0             0             0             0             0             0
7  31.12.2017  7             0             0             0             0             0             0             0
8  01.01.2018  8             1             0             0             0             0             0             0
9  02.01.2018  9             0             1             0             0             0             0             0
10 03.01.2018 10             0             0             1             0             0             0             0
   df_29.12.2017 df_30.12.2017 df_31.12.2017
1              0             0             0
2              0             0             0
3              0             0             0
4              0             0             0
5              1             0             0
6              0             1             0
7              0             0             1
8              0             0             0
9              0             0             0
10             0             0             0
```

I need name of days (mon,tue...)

Comment: ...and read `?as.Date`. Next time, please search before posting (you might have, but no trace of effort in your Q) and focus on one problem at a time ;) Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)


df %>%
  mutate(weekDay = lubridate::dmy(Data) %>% weekdays(),
         value = 1) %>%
  spread(key=weekDay, value=value, fill=0)
```